# Ruby, accessing a nested value in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following hash. Using ruby, I want to get the value of "runs". I can't figure out how to do it. If I do `my_hash['entries']`, I can dig down that far. If I take that value and dig down lower, I get this error:
`no implicit conversion of String into Integer:`

```
{"id"=>2582, "entries"=>[{"id"=>"7", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2588, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have an array inside the `entries` so you can access it using an index like this:

```
my_hash["entries"][0]["runs"]
```

You need to follow the same for accessing values inside the `runs` as it is also an array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to lookup values by `id`, [`Array#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) comes to the rescue:

```
h = {"id"=>2582, "entries"=>[{"id"=>"7", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2588}]}]}
#           ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ lookup element with id = 7 
h['entries'].detect { |e| e['id'] == 7 }['runs']
            .detect { |e| e['id'] == 2588 }
#⇒ { "id" => 2588 }
```

Comment: It is working fine. I didn't knew about `detect`, learned a new method, thanks. But I think `e['id'] = 7` should be `e['id'] == 7` right?

Comment: Oh, indeed, sorry for that. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your hash, as it's incomplete. So , guessing you have multiple run values like:

```
hash = {"id"=>2582, "entries"=>[{"id"=>"7", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2588}]},
                                {"id"=>"8", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2589}]},
                                {"id"=>"9", "runs"=>[{"id"=>2590}]}]}
```

Then, you can do

```
hash["entries"].map{|entry| entry["runs"]}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[{"id"=>2588}], [{"id"=>2589}], [{"id"=>2590}]]
```

Comment: Adding up more to your answer: `hash["entries"].map{|entry| entry["runs"]}.flatten.map{ |run| run["id"] }` will return only the ids.